# FadeIn текста в slick каруселе

Tags: javascript, анимация, slick.js

Доброй ночи, дорогие друзья.
Использую slick carousel. На каждом слайде есть текст, при появлении слайда или при скролле на новый слайд блок с текстом должен всплывать (например FadeIn).
Вопрос в том, как поймать действие появление нового слайда.
Понимаю, вопрос несерьезный, но хотелось бы разобраться.
В какую сторону копать?[image: Скрин карусели]

Comment: Открываете http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ и скроллите до `afterChange/beforeChange`

Comment: Разобрался, сделал через afterChange.
Убирал текст при swipe. Большое спасибо br3t за ответ.